# Comparing and finding duplicate array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

Higuys, Im working on a small program and part of its function is to find duplicate array.

Say i stored some numbers in     `mem[100][4]`
and there is another set of 4 numbers in     `temp[4]`     waiting to be stored.

The program checks to see if there are any identical set in `mem[100][4]`,
if no then the `temp[4]` set will be stored as  `mem[numR][4]`.

numR represents the total entries in the mem array and also the main result of my program.

But the output is either 0 or included duplicate. Anyone know whats wrong with my code?

```
 void Cord::checkDup(){
        int j, k, z=0;
        int swap = 0;

        temp[0] = i;
        temp[1] = x;
        temp[2] = y;
        temp[3] = c;

        //Ascending sort
        /* code not shown here*/


        //Check for duplicate
        for (j = 0; j < (numR-1);j++){
                if(
                        (mem[j][0] == temp[0]) &&
                        (mem[j][1] == temp[1]) &&
                        (mem[j][2] == temp[2]) &&
                        (mem[j][3] == temp[3])
                    ){
                        numR--; /* the reason behind this is because I first assumed it is a valid entry and incremented numR by 1 before the checking*/
                        return;

                }else{
                    continue;
                }
        }
        mem[numR - 1][0] = temp[0];
        mem[numR - 1][1] = temp[1];
        mem[numR - 1][2] = temp[2];
        mem[numR - 1][3] = temp[3];


    }
```

Comment: You could make `mem` a `std::set<std::array<int, 4>>` and completely forgo searching for duplicates.

Comment: What are i,x,y,c ? Are they members of the Cord object ? You are searching for any occurence of {i,x,y,c}, but not for duplicates.